# Facing interior label of grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules

The grid labeling is not going on the border, it always marked on the boundary of vector dataset?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using Clip extent by vector file from Data Frame -> Clip by Shape. Try to uncheck `Clip grids and graticules`. It may solve the problem.

[image]